# Switching from GDI/WinForms to WPF for custom UI elements

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I'm transitioning to using WPF after using WinForms for 6+ years. Previously, using `On_Paint`, and drawing with Graphics and Brushes and the like, I've created custom UI elements like the below:

[image: UI]

I'd like to duplicate this look using WPF but I'm not sure where to begin or how to do it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I remember talking with you about this a few weeks ago, have you looked at the standard templates? You just need to modify them (granted, easier said than done). As is this question is pretty broad. Perhaps you could look at the templates and ask a question about a specific piece? Here is the link to the templates for reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Yeah, I've tried to check that link out but there's just so much there I don't even know where to begin with it. I'm having trouble figuring out how to translate what I've done with GDI/Drawing into what I need to do with the templates you linked.

Comment: Hopefully my answer gets you started. Unfortunately the best way to approach ControlTemplates is, in my experience, a lot of trial and error. You'll get the hang of it though. Let me know if you need clarification or more help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is that you need to override the `ControlTemplate` for the button you are styling (do this in a resource for code reuse!).

The basic format would be:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" Key="MyAwesomeButtonStyle">
       ... Bunch of stuff including control template
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
   <Button Style="{StaticResource MyAwesomeButtonStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

To get a starting point for what the existing control template looks at, look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For a button specifically, look at [Button Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (you can get there from the first link by scrolling down a little and clicking the "Button Styles and Templates" link).

To match your picture, you will likely need to replace the wrapping `Border` element with as simple `Grid` and add a `Path` to get the parallelogram shape. `RadialGradientBrush` can be used for the background of the path to get the color effect.

Without a more narrow question, its hard to say *specifically* what you need (without taking the time to just figure out the template), but my advice would be to put the existing control template into your program and use it as an override for one of your buttons. Then modify pieces to learn what they do/affect. Finally, modify the correct pieces to look like you want.

Basically, trial and error is probably your best bet as far as learning how to modify/write these are concerned.

Comment: This code here - This goes in the XAML for my Window? Where would I put it if I wanted to make it available to multiple Windows in the same application?

Comment: You can put it into a `ResourceDictionary` in another XAML file and use the `MergedDictionaries` property to bring into each window. There's lots of documentation on that and it could even make a good new SO question once you are ready for that.

Answer (score 1):

When delving into WPF, it's best to forget everything you know about Win Forms and just pretend you're learning how to develop UIs for the first time.  Pretty much everything is different, so expect a good year or so of study and work before it really starts to gel.

You can do a lot with Control Templates, though your particular controls are complex enough in appearance that hard-coding the Paths for the borders may be a bit awkward.  You can get something close to the old GDI way of doing things using [DrawingVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742254%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which lets you define vector graphics in code.

Note that you even if you did use a DrawingVisual to get the particular look you're after, you'd still probably want to use it inside a ControlTemplate for Button.  This way you can take advantage of all the code that's already been written for Button and anybody using your template doesn't have to change out their Buttons for custom controls; all they have to do is apply your template to change how it looks.

Again, this is a deep and complex topic, so expect to do a lot of reading/tinkering before you have all of the concepts down.  Best of luck and happy coding; WPF is well worth the pain of entry.