# Drawing a Line based on Height/Width in a ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

This is a follow-up and more specific question to: 
[Switching from GDI/WinForms to WPF for custom UI elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664098/switching-from-gdi-winforms-to-wpf-for-custom-ui-elements)

I'm attempting to make a `ControlTemplate` to duplicate the look shown in my original question. The outside border is made up of 6 lines whose coordinates need to depend on the Height and Width of the button that the Template is applied to. Some coordinates will be percentages of the total, others need to be static offsets.

What is the syntax for binding X1, Y1, etc to these properties?

Alternatively, if there is a better way to draw that 6 sided shape as a border that still allows dependency on the Height and Width, I'm open to that as well.

This was the original code I used to generate the Points for drawing using GDI:

```
    int DiagonalOffset = 15;

    List<Point> pts = new List<Point>();
    pts.Add(new Point(offset, this.Height - offset));
    pts.Add(new Point(offset, DiagonalOffset));
    pts.Add(new Point(DiagonalOffset, offset));
    pts.Add(new Point(this.Width - offset, offset));
    pts.Add(new Point(this.Width - offset, this.Height - DiagonalOffset));
    pts.Add(new Point(this.Width - DiagonalOffset, this.Height - offset));
    pts.Add(new Point(offset, this.Height - offset));
```

I need to do the equivalent to this in my ControlTemplate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to data bind to the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties of the control that the `ControlTemplate` is applied to using a `TemplatedParent RelativeSource Binding`. Try this as an example, which will draw a `Line` diagonally across the control that the `ControlTemplate` is applied to:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Line X1="0.0" X2="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
        TemplatedParent}}" Y1="0" Y2="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={
        RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5" />
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Will this still work if the control resizes after the initial load?

Comment: @Sheridan Thank you, this is very close to what I am looking for. How can I subtract or add to the ActualHeight/ActualWidth before using it as a coordinate (or the equivalent)? As you can see I need to be able to offset.

Comment: It's a `Binding`, so yes... when the property value changes, the `Line` co-ordinates will change. *How can I subtract or add to the ActualHeight/ActualWidth before using it as a coordinate (or the equivalent)?*... you need to create an [`IMultiValueContverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx), but that's another story.

Comment: Binding to `ActualWidth` / `ActualHeight` always seemed dicey to me -- but I work with Silverlight, so maybe WPF is better about it.

Comment: *Binding to `ActualWidth` / `ActualHeight` always seemed dicey to me*... it's just `Binding` to `double` properties. I've never had any problem with it, even in highly advanced custom controls, using them in `IMultiValueConverter`s and `IMultiBinding`s.

Comment: @Sheridan sweet, that is useful.  I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use a `Path`, and allow it to stretch to the container size (eg, Grid).  So you could have something like this in the ControlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Grid Background="LightGray">
        <Path Data="M 0,2 L 2,0 L 10,0 L 10,8 L 8,10 L 0,10 Z" 
              Stretch="Fill"
              Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" 
              Margin="1"
        />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Path uses [vector-style graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.data(v=vs.110).aspx), so you can draw it to whatever scale you like and it will resize.

[image: path screenshot]